# Sleeping Position - Avoiding Mirrors

Tags: belief, practice

So, I was just reading up some Feng-Shui stuff, and I realized that sleeping in front of mirrors is apparently not good, as it may lead to something called 'soul-stealing'

Attached are a few websites claiming the same-

1. [Mirror and Feng Shui - 1](https://fengshuinexus.com/blog/mirror-facing-bed-feng-shui/)
2. [Mirror and Feng Shui - 2](https://www.thespruce.com/feng-shui-tips-for-a-mirror-facing-the-bed-1274767)

Do Hindus also believe in this practice? Is there any mention of the 'best sleeping position' in Hinduism? Does a mirror in front of a bed really change anything?

Comment: Not sure about any literature clearly saying that but my parents always asked not to keep mirrors against the bed. If there are any small mirror then turn upside down.

Comment: Dear close voters, Knowing whether a belief exists in Hinduism is not off-topic. Don't know how this is off-topic. Review properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be exact answer what you are looking for but here it goes.
I don't know about Feng-Shui, but in Hinduism best sleeping position is facing east direction. South is good too.

But strictly avoid sleep facing North and West. Specially North (Very very bad).